# OpenCV cvCaptureFromCAM returns null with PS3 Eye

Tags: c++, opencv

I've set up my ps3 eye with open CV however, when I call the function `cvCaptureFromCAM(0)` it always returns null. I'm using [these drivers](http://www.codelaboratories.com/products/eye) for my ps3 eye and OpenCV2.2.

I've tried many other solutions I found on StackOverflow and other blogs on the internet like using `CV_CAP_ANY` in place of 0 to even redesigning the whole code to use OpenCV2 format with `cv::VideoCapture capWebcam(0);` but still I get a null pointer indicating my camera cannot be accessed.

I know my ps3 eye works because I've tested it by video chatting on skype and it works like any other webcam.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Or better yet, has anyone successfully set up the PS3 eye for use with openCV?

PS: If any one would like to look at the code you could download a copy of it [here](http://www.18f4550.com/OpenCV_and_Emgu_CV/OpenCV_tut_1/Tracker7.zip)

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried newer OpenCV releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the C style of detecting the webcam..

```
int main()
{
    CvCapture *webcam = NULL;
    webcam = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);
    if(webcam!=NULL)
      {
       IplImage *frame = cvQueryFrame(webcam);
       cvShowImage("WEBCAM_TEST",frame);
       cvWaitKey(0);
       return 0;
      }
   else
       {
         std::cout<<"CAMERA NOT DETECTED"<<std::endl;
         return 0;
       }

}
```